# Cannot display base64 decoded image in a HTML tag using PHP

Tags: php, curl, base64, php-curl

Why I cannot display an image inside an HTML tag ?.

```
<?php
session_start();

$ch = curl_init( 'https://mighty-inlet-78383.herokuapp.com/api/hotels/imagedata');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    die(curl_error($ch));
    echo 'No responce';
}

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, true);

// get data from api to json
foreach($responseData AS $response) {

    $hotelImage = $response['hotelImage'];

    $imgdecord = base64_decode($hotelImage). "\n"; 

    if(empty($email)){
        echo "No responce from server";
    }
    else{
        echo '<br>';
        echo'
            <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $imgdecord . '" />
                </body>
            </html>    
        ';
        }
}

?>
```

It shows below result in the browser

> ���z�C�ZM�*]y�eb��3K�����<~_^%�HW �t}��-l��)Z/�2H����.r�M���g�q��kޭ��q�і��/�P���W��.�b�$/�a������O,U�S���*�5��\mr��8�ӓPs|�C|�u��W~l��t�l-��������9����%͓��E��ַ�5�]z���O���`��Tl���GO��oQ�E�����y�o�l�,児

My API returns values like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e8f2e81c15e30001791379e",
        "name": "harlyRox",
        "email": "hishansjc@gmail.com",
        "phone_number": 713677319,
        "hotelImage": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAYAAADPPjzCAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAP+6SURBVHhe7J0FYB3Htf6P0GLJkm1JlkySGWLG2I7DDG3StEnhFd//vcJrX5k5hddX5vaVU06TtkmaNE2TNszMTHYSc8ys
},..
]
```

Comment: if its in base64 already, you dont need to decode it, also the \n wont help anything. bypass this line `base64_decode($hotelImage). "\n";`

Comment: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $hotelImage . '" />`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It works !!!!. Thank you, sir...

Answer (score 1):

it works when I remove this line

```
$imgdecord = base64_decode($hotelImage). "\n";
```

and change this HTML tag to

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $hotelImage . '" />
```

as @LawrenceCherone mentioned above